# old website is still visible on domain

Tags: networking, ip, hosting, web-hosting, router

I have a problem. I had hosting on 000webhost and I had domain (szafor.pl) redirected to 000webhost.

Now I have hosting on vipower and the same domain I redirected to new hosting, I did it today.

On new hosting I have new version of website.

When I was at office I could see new version of my website. At home I still see old version which was on 000webhost. Why? I cleared webbrowser cache data, I reset my router. Where is the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I restart router again and it works